# How to find a string from multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm trying to update a state in my redux reducer by passing the deleted item id. The Id is located in tasks and associated column. What would a clean way to delete this item?

So far my reducer looks like this:

```
case DELETE_TASK:
  const update =  delete state.tasks[`${action.payload.id}`]
  const findIdCol = ?
  return {

  }


const initState = {
      tasks: {
        "task1": {
          id: "task1",
          content: "hello1"
        },
        "task2": {
          id: "task2",
          content: "hello2"
        },
        "task3": {
          id: "task2",
          content: "hello3"
        }
      },
      columns: {
        "column1": {
          id: "column1",
          taskIds: []
        },
        "column2": {
          id: "column2",
          taskIds: []
        },
        "column3": {
          id: "column3",
          taskIds: ["task3", "task1"]
        }
      },
      main: {
        "main": {
          id: "main",
          taskIds: ["task2"]
        }
      },
      columnOrder: ["column1", "column2", "column3"],
      mainOrder: ["main"]
    };
```

Comment: By deleting the item, do you mean removing the id from any of the columns? Filtering each column would be a solution, if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, I would need to delete the id in the associated column. I believe const update =  delete state.tasks[`${action.payload.id}`] removes the object from tasks which is the first step next is to delete the id in the column. I would need to check all existing columns e.g. columns and main

Comment: @Freddy : doing `delete` on the state directly or any other way of modifying its properties doesn't seem to be ***clean*** whatsoever. Instead, I'd [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271484/11299053) to do copy-modify-replace thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the columns object into its entries, allowing you to loop over each entry You can recreate the columns object, using reduce:

```
state.columns = Object.entries(state.columns).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  v.taskIds = v.taskIds.filter(taskId => taskId !== action.payload.id)
  a[k] = v
  return a
}, {})
```

Demo:

```js
const state = {
  tasks: {
    task1: { id: 'task1', content: 'hello1' },
    task2: { id: 'task2', content: 'hello2' },
    task3: { id: 'task2', content: 'hello3' }
  },
  columns: {
    column1: { id: 'column1',taskIds: [] },
    column2: { id: 'column2',taskIds: [] },
    column3: { id: 'column3',taskIds: ['task3', 'task1'] }
  },
  main: {
    main: { id: 'main', taskIds: ['task2']}
  },
  columnOrder: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
  mainOrder: ['main']
}


const id = 'task1'

state.columns = Object.entries(state.columns).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  v.taskIds = v.taskIds.filter(taskId => taskId !== id)
  a[k] = v
  return a
}, {})

console.log(state)
```

You would replace `id` with `action.payload.id` in this case.

If you wanted to reuse this code, you could make it into a function:

```js
const state = {
  tasks: {
    task1: { id: 'task1', content: 'hello1' },
    task2: { id: 'task2', content: 'hello2' },
    task3: { id: 'task2', content: 'hello3' }
  },
  columns: {
    column1: { id: 'column1',taskIds: [] },
    column2: { id: 'column2',taskIds: [] },
    column3: { id: 'column3',taskIds: ['task2', 'task1'] }
  },
  main: {
    main: { id: 'main', taskIds: ['task2']}
  },
  columnOrder: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
  mainOrder: ['main']
}


const id = 'task2'

const removeId = (o, id) => {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    v.taskIds = v.taskIds.filter(taskId => taskId !== id)
    a[k] = v
    return a
  }, {})
}

state.columns = removeId(state.columns, id)
state.main = removeId(state.main, id)


console.log(state)
```

Comment: What if task1 was in main? since this is only removing the id that is located in columns

Comment: @Freddy. You could use the exact same piece of code, but replace state.columns with state.main

Answer (score 0):

To keep your reducer function pure and state immutable, I would not recommend to update the properties of the state directly (neither with `reduce()` returning an object, nor with `delete` operator). *The cleanest* approach here would be to follow the pattern

- grab the state
- put it into variable
- modify relevant parts
- replace the original state with its modified copy

That would give you something, like this (e.g. if you wish to remove `task3` from your default state):

```js
//dependencies
const { createStore } = Redux
     
//store initialization
const defaultState = {tasks:{"task1":{id:"task1",content:"hello1"},"task2":{id:"task2",content:"hello2"},"task3":{id:"task3",content:"hello3"}},columns:{"column1":{id:"column1",taskIds:[]},"column2":{id:"column2",taskIds:[]},"column3":{id:"column3",taskIds:["task3","task1"]}},main:{"main":{id:"main",taskIds:["task2"]}},columnOrder:["column1","column2","column3"],mainOrder:["main"]},
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'DELETE_TASK': {
            //destructuring state into parts to be modified
            const {tasks,columns,main} = state,
                  {payload: taskIdToDelete} = action
            //iterate through tasks to delete matching id's
            Object.entries(tasks).forEach(([key, {id}]) => id == taskIdToDelete && delete tasks[key])
            //iterate through columns to filter out deleted task           
            Object.entries(columns).forEach(([key, {taskIds}]) => columns[key]['taskIds'] = taskIds.filter(taskId => taskId != taskIdToDelete))
            //filter out deleted task from main           
            main.main.taskIds = main.main.taskIds.filter(taskId => taskId != taskIdToDelete)
            return {...state, tasks, columns, main}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)
//dispatch 'DELETE_TASK'
store.dispatch({type:'DELETE_TASK', payload: 'task3'})
//log modified state
console.log(store.getState())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.4/redux.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.1/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```